# Installing face_recognition (python) causes command not found error

Tags: command-line, python, python3

#### What I have done

I followed [this tutorial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/face_recognition), did

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and installed this Dockerfile

```
# This is a sample Dockerfile you can modify to deploy your own app 
based on face_recognition

FROM python:3.4-slim
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing \
 build-essential \
 cmake \
 gfortran \
 git \
 wget \
 curl \
 graphicsmagick \
 libgraphicsmagick1-dev \
 libatlas-dev \
 libavcodec-dev \
 libavformat-dev \
 libboost-all-dev \
 libgtk2.0-dev \
 libjpeg-dev \
 liblapack-dev \
 libswscale-dev \
 pkg-config \
 python3-dev \
 python3-numpy \
 software-properties-common \
 zip \
 && apt-get clean && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
RUN cd ~ && \
 mkdir -p dlib && \
 git clone -b 'v19.7' --single-branch 
 https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git dlib/ && \
 cd  dlib/ && \
 python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS`
```

And continued with these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
mkdir build; cd build; cmake .. -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=0 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1; cmake --build .
cd ..
python3 setup.py install --yes USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS --no DLIB_USE_CUDA
pip3 install face_recognition
```

#### My error

I run `face_recognition` in terminal, and I get:

```
face_recognition: command not found
```

I check `/home/capitan/.local/bin` to see if the `face_recognition` is there, and it is. Contents of `face_recognition` include:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from face_recognition.cli import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(main())
```

There are other `.py` files in this location that work just fine, such as `f2py`, and `gifmaker.py`. I'm not sure why Ubuntu is telling me that this command is not found. Everything else seemed to work properly.

**How do I get rid of the *`command not found`* error and get the command *`face_recognition`* to work properly in the terminal?**

Python3 runs fine, but within terminal with `python3`:

```
>>> import dlib
```

outputs:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

**Ubuntu version**: Ubuntu 17.10, x64
**CPU**: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4300 @ 2.10GHz × 2 
**GPU**: No GPU, integrated graphics

Comment: Does starting it directly with `~/.local/bin/face_recognition` work? Does your `$PATH` contain `~/.local/bin`?

Comment: It does not work in its directory unless I use `python` in front of it. My path does contain that.

Comment: So if you do `alias face_recognition='python ~/.local/bin/face_recognition'` that essentially solves your problem?